# Custom paging in grid view control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, custom-paging

I want custom pagination in my gridview control. The first option is to fetch only required row from the data base. But what I want is I am fetching all rows from the database and storing them into datatable. Now is there any option that I can bind only some of the rows of datatable to gridview based on page size and page index so that I no need to connect to database every time on page change event?

Comment: be sure to use the green checkbox to mark the 'best answer'! It's part of the reputation system at StackOverflow. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the Gridview `PageIndexChanging` event and setup a New page index.

like...

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   gridView.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["DataTable"];
   gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for you response.. But this will do the default paging and will not help me in custom paging....